# Wordpress auto update server

Tags: php, wordpress, server

So, my company hosts hundreds of wordpress sites. We turned off auto updating of wordpress core files because we have modified core code for better SEO / better security. Every so often we grab the next version and move our changes over, test it and then push it out to all of our sites manually.

I would like to create a server that helps with pushing our new / updated core code to all the wordpress sites through the auto update.

Essentially I am looking for our wordpress intances to auto-update from a server on OUR side instead of from wordpress servers.

Comment: It is unclear exactly what you're asking for. Additionally, this question does not seem to relate directly to programming.

Comment: Well, funny thing....I don't believe that stack overflow is ONLY for coding. However, to clarify, wordpress updates its core files by checking wordpress.org's API. I am looking to point my wordpress installations towards my OWN API that acts like wordpress.org's API but instead serves up our own code.

Comment: You might want to re-read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Why you need to get the updates from WP auto update service? You could just push new files versions with a server script, no?

Comment: Because our IT team is overworked and they have hundreds of WP sites to update. It'd be a billion times easier if I could just recreate the API. If this hasn't been done please just say so and I will get working on it.

Comment: I know it is possible to update a plugin not through wordpress.org (see [this guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates--wp-25181)), but for the core I honestly don't think it is possible without hacking deeply in _update-core.php_.

Comment: I was thinking of possibly just pointing wp-includes/update.php to our server  on line 103 and having an API server there that works very similar to api.wordpress.org

Comment: Why don't you use something like a simple git repository which holds the WP core?

Comment: omg wow I see what you mean.....that may actually work....can't believe i didn't think of it before. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using something like GIT for version control, you can set up your altered wordpress core files in it's own repo and then include them in your deployments as a submodule.

An example would be this repo where they have set up Wordpress as a submodule.

https://github.com/Darep/wordpress-boilerplate

Instead of using the official Wordpress repo as the submodule, you would use your altered one.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think I will be doing something very similar instead of recreating their api...

Comment: From a BA perspective, I would also recommend not altering core framework files in any instance.  Given, I don't know all your business requirements or reasons for altering the files, if one of the primary issues is security, I would look into a managed hosting solution.  The additional hosting costs are typically offset by the savings of your internal maintenance.

http://wpengine.com

Comment: Unfortunately those decisions are above my pay grade at this company. I agree with you, however they have determined that their are certain SEO and security changes that are mandatory and refuse to remove them from core. So I am stuck within those confines

Comment: Strange that they would think that changes to WPCore would help SEO as that should all be handled via theme hooks.